# Could same name and logo be used on app store

Tags: ios

I am uploading two versions of similar application on app store- free version and the paid version. Can I use same logo and same name of the application

Comment: To be honest: that is a very outdated practice. You should just offer one app and offer the premium upgrade using in-app purchases instead. Splitting into two versions complicates deployments, development, complicates push notifications, makes the UX really bad to install two apps. I do not think there is a single upside to splitting it into two apps.

Comment: Both versions will target different region users hence it's mandate to upload paid version separately.